# the first animation has run out and after I excute the second animation,but the view's status has restore

Tags: android, animation

How can I continue the second animation base on the status of first Animation?

```
 TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, desX, 0, desY);
 ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 0.2f, 1, 1Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
 AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);
 set.addAnimation(translateAnim);
 set.addAnimation(scaleAnim);
 set.setFillAfter(true);
 set.setDuration(300);
 mView.startAnimation(set);
```

when the animation end,I want to start another animation ,but it come back in the initial status.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, desX, 0, desY);
         ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 0.2f, 1, 1Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
         AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);
         set.addAnimation(translateAnim);
         set.addAnimation(scaleAnim);
         set.setFillEnabled(true);
         set.setFillAfter(true);
         set.setDuration(300);
         mView.startAnimation(set);
```

add these lines in your code:

```
set.setFillEnabled(true);
set.setFillAfter(true);
```

Comment: I have add it to my code.I know it will keep the statu when the animation finish.but I just want to the view don't back to initial position when the seconde animation start running

Comment: Then you have to use object animater, it supports from api level 11.

Comment: try this tutorial, it will helps you  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html